# Dos componentes individuales llaman a un mismo output en Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Tengo dos componentes iguales pero con diferentes datos en las entradas (@Input) y las salidas (@output) pero el output del segundo componente lo atrapa el primer componente. Es decir como si en realidad componentes fuesen el mismo.

```
<cropper [aspectRatio]="1 / 1" [square]="true" (output)="imageChanged1($event)"></cropper>

<cropper [aspectRatio]="2 / 1" [square]="false" (output)="imageChanged2($event)"></cropper>
```

Este es un ejemplo básico código de typescript del componente

```
import { Component,, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'cropper',
  templateUrl: './image-cropper.component.html',
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class ImageCropperComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() aspectRatio: string = "1/1";
  @Input() square = false;
  @Output() output = new EventEmitter<any>();

  // Imagen
  image: File = null;

  constructor() {
    
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  // image-cropper
  onImagenChange(e: any) {
    this.image = e.target.files[0];
    this.output.emit({
      image: this.image
    });
  }
}
```

Este es el código básico del HTML

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('fileInput').click();">Buscar</button>

<input type="file" style="display: none" id="fileInput" accept="image/jpeg, image/png" (change)="onImagenChange($event)" />
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que los input y output del primer componente funcionen solo en ese componente?
Lo mismo para el segundo componente con sus propios input y outout

Comment: `@Input` y `@Output` pertenecen a cada instancia del componente, no son compartidos. Si algo no funciona como esperas posiblemente se deba a que las instancias del componente `cropper` en algún punto están compartiendo algún recurso.

Answer (score 0):

Cada instancia de la clase ImageCropperComponent emitirá eventos diferentes y estos serán capturados por la función que tu asignes. Según veo en tu ejemplo serían imageChanged1 y imageChanged2 respectivamente. Por favor comparte más código para ayudarte mejor.